# Getting all entries in a particular number of months

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I am creating a program in change oil monitoring, which has a table units that has a field lastdatechangeoil.

I need a code that will show all units that has not undergone change oil 3 months or more than 3 months.

Please help me with a code in java using MySQL as the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MySQL query command with this `WHERE` clause will find the records you want.

```
WHERE lastdatechangeoil <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

as long as that information is stored in a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column.